# file:///android_asset in IOS

Tags: html, ios, angular, ionic-framework, path

I'm using angular and ionic. I need access to html file. I did correctly with Android but I don't know how to do it with iOS

```
if(this.platform.is('android')) {
  browser = this.iab.create('file:///android_asset/www/assets/formAdyen.html', this.paymentGatewayObject.target, this.paymentGatewayObject.options)
}
else {
  browser = this.iab.create('assets/formAdyen.html', this.paymentGatewayObject.target, this.paymentGatewayObject.options)
}
```

The iOS version doesn't work. How can I get the path of this html file?

Comment: I doubt IOS will allow that. They have several security features that Android doesn't want to use. You might need to use a different app or store your files somewhere else

Comment: and other way to access to a file? can I insert the file in anywhere or anyhow to use it ?

Comment: You should probably ask in [Apple forums](https://discussions.apple.com/)